# how to plot calendar heatmap by month

Tags: python

This seems quite simple, but for some reason, I'm struggling to get it working the way I want.

This is the data I have.

[image: Sales by Date]

I want to show it as a heat map broken down by month, for all months, like below:

[image: Calendar heatmap]

I tried calplot, but unable to figure out making it show by month and the July package started giving me all sorts of conversion errors.

Please assist.

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested you use case with a minimal setup python 3.9.12 and calplot==0.1.7.5. Here is the code.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import calplot

# Generate example data
np.random.seed(0)
dates = pd.date_range(start='2024-01-01', end='2024-12-31', freq='D')
sales = np.random.randint(100, 1000, size=len(dates))

# Create a DataFrame
data = pd.DataFrame({'Date': dates, 'Sales': sales})

# Reshape the data for calplot
data.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

# Plotting
calplot.calplot(data['Sales'], cmap='YlGn', colorbar=True, figsize=(30, 2))

plt.title('Sales in July 2024')
plt.show()
```

[image]

EDIT 1:

You can get similar output with july library
`july==0.1.3` and `Python 3.9.12`

```py
import july
import numpy

np.random.seed(0)
dates = pd.date_range(start='2024-01-01', end='2024-12-31', freq='D')
sales = np.random.randint(100, 1000, size=len(dates))

# Create a DataFrame
data = pd.DataFrame({'Date': dates, 'Sales': sales})

# Reshape the data for calplot
data.set_index('Date', inplace=True)


july.calendar_plot(dates=data.index, data=data.Sales)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I was able to get this myself. But I want the output to show each month separately and the dates in them. Please help.

Comment: @Arun I edited with the same example but in July framework I hope it helps you :)